# Visual Equalizer Bars in C# Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-forms-designer

For my college project, I have decided to create a rhythm game which is similar to [Beatmania](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beatmania), with notes falling from the top of the screen to an area where the user needs to make an input.

Now, for the main menu, I would like to include a visual equalizer, with bars moving up and down in rhythm with the music that is playing in the background:

This would need to be customisable to be added into the main menu (transparency so that background behind the bars is visible etc.

Currently, I have been looking all over the internet to try and find a way to program such a thing. However (unless I'm using the term wrong), all results come up with actually equalising sound based on bass etc. and since I'm somewhat of a C# beginner I am baffled as to what is said.

[XNA Visual Equalizer Video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yo3qc7FIBlQ) - this is the closest thing I have found to what I would like. Unfortunately, I have no idea how to use XNA and there is a chance that my college will not install XNA, so working on the project will take longer, as I can only work on it at home. So Windows Forms would be preferred.

Any input on this would be appreciated. If you have any questions then please ask :)

Edit: (Not sure how to narrow this question down) - I need a Visual Equalizer in Windows Forms, does Windows have such a method, class or reference that can be used right off the bat without having to download plugins, extensions etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is called an Audio spectrum analyzer. XNA is commonly used in games, and should just be included as a .dll in your files. I don't think you have to install that b/c you can publish XNA content as a native executable.

However, instead of reinventing the wheel, the nice folks at code project have [shared a project that analyzes the frequency of sound](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/797537/Making-an-Audio-Spectrum-analyzer-with-Bass-dll-Cs). You should be able to modify this and get it to work to your specifications.

Comment: Have been taking a look at this. So far it looks great. Just need to make it work on a Windows Form, as the UIs on the app are in XAML format.

Comment: Ah, he's using a WPF form, XAML just allows some of the types of properties to be stored in a XML style place. You should consider upgrading to wpf as it gives you greater control than winforms. [.net Perls is a really good resource if you want to delve into that](http://www.dotnetperls.com/window-wpf)

Comment: So they have the same properties as Windows Forms? Meaning all thats in the forms is also in the WPF forms? If that's the case then it would be much easier to use those, was messing around with them and they seem more powerful.

Comment: Pretty much, the only gotchas are some small things like how Color.Black in winForms would be Brushes.Black, but other than that it's pretty straight forwards and allows much more application customization. If you feel like stepping up to the next level WPF would be a good choice. [Microsoft's WPF documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970268(v=vs.110).aspx) and stack overflow are your friends if you need help with specific wpf gotchas.

Comment: Thanks Kiro. You've been a great help! If I could upvote your post I would :)